# Any idea how to do this in css?

Tags: html, css

Any idea how to do this using css ?

[image: Any idea how to do this using css]

I'm looking for a good and clear way to do this.

Comment: Vertical and horizontal align center ?

Comment: @Minuwan Did you find any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="line"></div>
<span>OR</span>
<div class="line"></div>​
```

**CSS**

```
div.line
{
width:1px;
background-color:Gray;
height:40px;
margin:10px;
}

span
{
font-weight:bold;
}
```

**[Live Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/UsYwT/)**

​

Answer (score 4):

**HTML**

```
<div class="orWrapper">Or</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.orWrapper {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.orWrapper:before, 
.orWrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
}
​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CNhYh/)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is just use three divs and border property:
your html:

```
<div class="vertical">
</div>
<div>
OR
</div>
<div class="vertical">
</div>
```

your css  :

```
.vertical{
    border-left:thin solid black;
    height:30px;
    margin-left:10px;
}​
```

fiddle for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/SURzN/

Answer (score 0):

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fTGuV/

css:

```
.line
{
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
    border: solid 0px #000000;
    width:1px;
    border-left-width: 2px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="line">
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div>OR</div>
<div class="line">
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="line"><div class="txt">Or</div> <span></span></div>​
```

CSS

```
span{height:100%; display:block; margin:0 15px; border-left:1px solid black}
.line{width:30px; margin:10px;  position:relative; height:200px; text-align:center}
.txt{position:absolute; top:45%; left:4px; width:20px; height:25px; background:white}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ux8e8/1/)

​

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing i did :-

```
​<div Class="myclass"></div>
<div>OR</div>
<div Class="myclass"></div>​
```

CSS

```
 ​.myclass{
        width:1px;
        height:30px;
        background-color:black;
    margin-left:10px;

    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/drWXG/)

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it all in the same box...

**HTML**

```
<span class="vertical-bar">
    <span>Or</span>
</span>​
```

**CSS**

```
.vertical-bar {
    background: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2179487/black_pixel.png) center top repeat-y;
    float: left;
    padding: 100px 0;
}

.vertical-bar span {
    background-color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PjPAU/